# Is there a way to show an image in a new window using jquery?

Tags: jquery

Here is my code for it

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#happymyleast').css('display', 'none');
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#reveal').click(function() {
    window.open('testpage.html');
    $('#happymyleast').show();
  });
});
```

```css
#happymyleast {
  position: absolute;
  top: 119px;
  left: 71px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: #FFCC00;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<p id="happymyleast"></p>
<button id="reveal">Reveal</button>
```

What I'm looking to do when I click on the reveal button I want the image or the css shape that I've built to show on another page. Is that something that is possible to achieve using jQuery?

Comment: Opening an image is easy - just `window.open()` with the URL of the image. What do you mean by 'css shape' though?

Comment: I added the window.open() to the code and that works fine. If I add in what I've built that may make it clearer.

Comment: I will edit my question and add the css also that way you can see what I've done.

Comment: Why don't you include the javascript/css in the head of the new page that you are opening?

Comment: I'm about to do that now. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#happymyleast').css('display', 'none');
});
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#reveal').click(function(){
        var sub_window= window.open();
        var content=$('#happymyleast').html();
        //var styles=$('style').clone();
        var styles=$('style').clone().wrap('<div/>').parent().html();
        var full_content ='<head>'+styles+'</head>'+'<body>'+content+'</body>';
        //console.log(styles);
        sub_window.document.write(full_content);

    });
});
```

If you put image inside the p you'll be able to seee it. Or just type 'Hello Worl' inside it, and you'll be able to see it.

I think you are searching for something like this

I have made an example, but I am not able to host it on jsfiddle, because jsfiddle is blocking `document.write`

Comment: I've added your code to my code it opens a blank page so what I'm going to do is add my stylesheet I used to create the css into my new page and that way the happymyleast shape will show up on the other page. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks for your help I looked at the fiddle and its exactly what I want so thanks alot.

Answer (score 1):

opening an image on a new page is simple:

```
window.open($("#your_image").attr("src"), "_blank")
```

now for the css if this one is generated dynamically and you want it to appear in a new page you must use AJAX and php to dynamically write your current css into an external css file and then call it within the new page !